# Open results submit form php in fancybox

Tags: php, forms, fancybox, submit, fancybox-3

I need to open the results of a form in php after submit button, in a fancybox box.
This is the form:

```
<table width="300" height="60">
    <tr style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url("");">
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:60px;">
            <form action="dir/motore.php" method="post" name="datiUtenti">
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="vin" value="VG3XDRHKH22225555" onclick="this.value='';" style="margin-top:2px; border-color:white;font-size: 22px; width: 255px;  height: 45px; margin-left:30px;"/></br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-color:white;">
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid white;">
            <input type="submit" class="button" style="border-color:white; width:100%;" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is that valid xml/xhtml?

Comment: yes, i need a box with inside the results of motore.php.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you take a look at examples? http://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/MJYOOd?editors=1000 and http://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/JEVLgN?editors=1010

Comment: yes, if i insert data-fancybox data-src="#hidden-content" href="javascript:;"  in <input ..............>, the box open empty.

Comment: the input button don't processing the script php if i insert data-fancybox